# how to keep speed duration the same despite the distance changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, math

I have this problem with wanting to keep speed the same despite the distance it travel using transition and transition duration. I think i figure out a solution but I'm not sure on what the correct way would be to apply it. Let say if you have a element with a transition of all duration of 1s and traveling 200px left, now let say if it distance change to 400px left so to keep speed the same

```
400/200 == 2 and duration of 1s/2 = 0.5
```

right? is that sound? And if this is sound how would i apply this to both the x and y axis of it moving over distance but keep it same speed?

So let say if I have a problem like

```
var startX = 0, startY = 0, endX = 200, endY = 200, duration = 1, normalDistancePer1s = 200;

//change end position to something else

endX = endY = 400;

//normal distance is the time it take for it to travel the normal set distance speed

var diffXDis = endX/normalDistancePer1s; //2

var newDur = duration/diffXDis;// 0.5
```

how do i combine the x and y to get the right duration to be set for css property animation-duration? The goal is to make the speed look the same no matter in which direction and how far it have to travel. Just having a duration of 1 for everything will make the object look slow in some distance and fast in other. I want it to look the same speed no matter what distance.

---

REPLY TO Toran Sharma

To address your response as a possible answer so long as i understand it what you are saying is there could be two solution.

One being that:

```
//sudo code:
x = 400, y = 400, normalTravelTime = 1, nomralTravelDistance = 200;
hyp = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
//normal distance divide by new distance
diffPos = hyp/200
//divide new different position by duration
newDuration = normalTraveTime/diffPos
```

I turn the above sudo code into js code and got this:

```
//js code:
var x = 400, y = 400, normalTravelTime = 1, nomralTravelDistance = 200;
var hyp = Math.sqrt(x^2 + y^2);//0
//normal distance divide by new distance
var diffPos = hyp/200;//0
//divide new different position by duration
var newDuration = normalTravelTime/diffPos;//Infinity
```

And the other solution seem too refer to see which one is larger and that'll be the distance:

```
x_speed = x_distance / time
y_speed = y_distance / time
```

but what if i'm going backwards?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: hi, if I don't get it wrong,  then when the distance is 400px, the speed would still be 200px/s(as you said to keep it the same) and the duration should be 2s?

distance = velocity * duration;
   200   = 200      * 1;
   400   = 200      * 2;

Answer (score 4):

## Speed, Distance and Time

`Speed = Distance / Time`

You have a desired speed, and a known distance that needs to be travelled, so the thing that remains left to calculate is the time that it will take.

Rearranging the speed equation to make time the subject on the left hand side:
`Time = Distance / Speed`

So to get your object to travel the known distance at your desired speed, it will take `distance/speed` units of time to get there.

## 2D Movement

If the movement is happening in 2d, then then you will have two distances that needs to be travelled, one in the x (horizontal) direction, and one in the y (vertical) direction.

You can draw these two distances as two shorter sides of a triangle. The longest side of the triangle (hypotenuse) will be the actual length travelled by the object.

```
 |\
 | \
y|  \ hyp
 |   \
 ------
   x
```

This actual distance is what will set the length of time the object will take.
We can calculate the length of the hypotenuse using Pythagoras' theorem:
`hyp = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`

As before we use `Time = Distance / Speed` to calculate the time it will take to travel the distance, the hypotenuse of the triangle, at your chosen speed.

#### NB

It is worth noting that for the object to travel directly from the start to the finish, the duration of movement needs to be the same for the movement in both the x and y directions, otherwise the object would finish one component of its travel before the other. This means that unless the x and y distance are the same, the x and y components of the velocity will be different.

If you need these velocity components, we go back to the original definition of speed:
`Speed = Distance / Time`
Here we know the distance for the x and y components of the travel, and know the time we want the movement to take from above, so we plug these in to find the individual velocity components:

```
x_speed = x_distance / time
y_speed = y_distance / time
```

#### Update 1

I think your pseudo code and JavaScript looks like you have understood. The main point is, as you implement, that if your speed is constant, then the duration of the movement scales in proportion to the distance that is being travelled.

My suggestion would be that you do define your desired speed outright and use that to calculate the duration, that way you don't have to think in terms of before and after a change.

Note that 100^2 is no the square of 100, use Math.pow(100,2) or just 100*100.

I am note sure what you mean about going backwards, as you will see below it doesn't matter what direction is being travelled, i.e. which the start or end x or y is larger, as we square those distances anyway to work out the length of the actual distance travelled.

I include a code snippet to run to show animations with the same duration compared to same speed (and therefore varying durations), I hope this helps clarify (though the code isn't very clean):

```js
function setDurations(speed /* in units of px/s */)
{
  let styles = document.styleSheets[0]; // get the stylesheet with the keyframe definitions, 0 for this snippet
  let keyframeRules = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < styles.cssRules.length; i++)
  {
    // go through rules in the stylesheet and check if they are a keyframe rule, and add it to the array if it is.
    if (styles.cssRules[i].type == window.CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE)
    {
      //console.log(styles.cssRules[i]);
      keyframeRules.push(styles.cssRules[i]);
    }
  }

  let sameSpeedElements = document.getElementsByClassName('sameSpeed');
  
  let durationOutput = document.getElementById('durationOutput');
  durationOutput.innerText = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < sameSpeedElements.length; i++)
  {
    let keyframeRule = keyframeRules[i];
    let fromStyles = keyframeRule.cssRules[0].style;
    let toStyles = keyframeRule.cssRules[1].style;

    let xStart = fromStyles['left'];
    let yStart = fromStyles['top'];
    let xEnd = toStyles['left'];
    let yEnd = toStyles['top'];

    // Note that unset rules are set to empty string.

    // Trim off px and cast to a number;
    xStart = Number(xStart.slice(0, -2));
    yStart = Number(yStart.slice(0, -2));
    xEnd = Number(xEnd.slice(0,-2));
    yEnd = Number(yEnd.slice(0,-2));

    let xDist = xEnd-xStart;
    let yDist = yEnd-yStart;
    //Note that order start and end, and thus the sign of these doesn't matter as we will square it.

    let dist = Math.sqrt(xDist*xDist + yDist*yDist);

    let duration = dist/speed;
    sameSpeedElements[i].style.animationDuration = duration + "s";
    
    durationOutput.innerText += `SameSpd${i+1} animation-duration: ${duration}s\n`;
  }
 }
 
 let speedInput = document.getElementById('speedInput');
 
 speedInput.addEventListener('change', () => {setDurations(Number(speedInput.value))});
 
 setDurations(Number(speedInput.value));
```

```css
.container
{
  position: relative;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.animated
{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
.sameDuration
{
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.sameSpeed
{
  /*
   animation-duration to to be set per element to keep same speed
  */
}

#sameDur1, #sameSpd1
{
  animation-name: anim1;
}

#sameDur2, #sameSpd2
{
  animation-name: anim2;
}

#sameDur3, #sameSpd3
{
  animation-name: anim3;
}

#sameDur4, #sameSpd4
{
  animation-name: anim4;
}

@keyframes anim1
{
  from
  {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  
  to
  {
    left: 300px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes anim2
{
  from
  {
    left: 0px;
    top: 20px;
  }
  
  to
  {
    left: 400px;
    top: 20px;
  }
}
@keyframes anim3
{
  from
  {
    left: 0px;
    top: 40px;
  }
  
  to
  {
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes anim4
{
  from
  {
    left: 300px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  
  to
  {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
All divs have the same animation-duration (3s):
<div class="container">
  <div class="animated sameDuration" id="sameDur1">
    sameDur 1
  </div>
  <div class="animated sameDuration" id="sameDur2">
    sameDur 2
  </div>
  <div class="animated sameDuration" id="sameDur3">
    sameDur 3
  </div>
  <div class="animated sameDuration" id="sameDur4">
    sameDur 4
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
All divs are travelling at the same speed:
<br/>
Input speed:
<input id="speedInput" style="width:30px;" value="100"/> px/s
<div class="container">
  <div class="animated sameSpeed" id="sameSpd1">
    sameSpd 1
  </div>
  <div class="animated sameSpeed" id="sameSpd2">
    sameSpd 2
  </div>
  <div class="animated sameSpeed" id="sameSpd3">
    sameSpd 3
  </div>
  <div class="animated sameSpeed" id="sameSpd4">
    sameSpd 4
  </div>
</div>

<div id="durationOutput">
</div>
```

Comment: I reply to your answer in my questionn

Comment: @L2L2L I have updated my answer to try and clarify further.

Comment: cool explanation... i feel the rest is up to me now to fully gain more understanding of what I'm trying to do. But thanks for your time and effort likes up.